# Is any group the group of units of some ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I was wondering if there was a way to see any group $G$ as a subgroup of the inverse group of a ring, $G \leq A^\times$?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Take the group ring over your favorite field.

Comment: For a finite group with $n$ elements it suffices to say that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ which is a subgroup of $M_n(\Bbb{R})^\times$, sending the permutation $i\to \sigma(i)$ to the matrix $M_{ab} = 1$ if $\sigma(a)=b$, $M_{ab}=0$ otherwise. When the group is infinite it works the same way replacing $M_n(\Bbb{R})$ by the endomorphism ring of an infinite vector space whose basis has the same cardinality as $G$. The group ring $\Bbb{R}[G]$ is the subring generated by those matrices/endomorphisms.

Comment: The question in the title is much more interesting than the one you actually pose.

Comment: You've asked two different questions in the title and body (possibly unintentionally), and the title question is harder, has a different answer, and is also a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the group algebra $\mathbb{C}G$ which consist of the formal linear combinations of the form $$\sum_{g \in G}\alpha_g g$$
and where the algebra operations are the obvious ones. Note that we have an obvious inclusion $G \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}G$.  Then $G \subseteq(\mathbb{C}G)^\times$. Note however that in general the latter inclusion can be strict.

Comment: I think the algebra operations may not be so obvious to people who have never seen them before. To be explicit, we define $(\sum_{g\in G}\alpha_g g)\cdot (\sum_{h\in G}\beta_h h) = \sum_{g, h \in G}\alpha_g\beta_hgh$. Collecting like terms, we can put this into the form of a linear combination of elements of $G$, equal to $\sum_{g\in G}\big[(\sum_{x,y\in G: xy = g}\alpha_x\beta_y)g\big]$.

Comment: @Qwertiops Thanks for your comment. We get used to things when we use them a lot and we forget that some things may not be obvious :)